# Cython function and required CBLAS headers

Tags: cython

I'm trying to use the Cython functions available in the package python-deltasigma. The docs describing the package are found here [1](https://python-deltasigma.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), see the section on optional dependencies.  After installing the dependencies, and the optional dependencies (at least I thought), I'm not getting access to the cython variants of the _simulateDSM function.  I can get the function to run, but it is using the CPython (slowest) implementation.  I ran np.show_config() to see if the CBLAS headers were available to be used, and I got the following:

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

I'm not experienced in reading this output, but I'm guessing I did not successfully install the needed CBLAS extension.  Can anyone tell me a procedure to do this correctly?

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing you should report to the maintainers of the package: https://github.com/ggventurini/python-deltasigma/issues

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately I don't think the package is actively maintained, so I was hoping to get a hint from someone who may be familiar with Cython.